# Simple Android SQLlite connection to MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, database-connection

I have created a database within an Android app which has one table and four columns. I simply want to update the information in the android app with the same table stored on the MySQL database.

The MySQL database is hosted with an ISP.

what's the simplest was to do this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no simple answer. You need a webserver that your phone can connect to and then have to use and `AsyncTask` or `Service` to connect to that server, download the data, and update the local table.

Comment: Do you know any simple tutorials or guide on how to do this?

Comment: There's no single tutorial that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone trying to do this is used a PHP file to connect to the DB and HTTP to jet a JSON file

Tutorial: http://m-zeeshanarif.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/android-connecting-to-server-mysql.html

Combined this with making is an asynchronous task:

Tutorial: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.Uvz81XmPO00

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. This is good :

[mysqlToSqllite](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776/)